# What should be the characteristic polynomial for $A^{-1}$ and adj$A$ if the characteristic polynomial of $A$ be given?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let the characteristic polynomial of $A$ be $\psi_A(x):=p(x)$. If $A$ be non-singular, then find that the characteristic polynomial of $A^{-1}$ and adj$(A)$.

My attempt:
We have 
\begin{align*}
&\psi_{A^{-1}}(x)\\
=&|xI_n-A^{-1}|\\
=&|A^{-1}||xA-I_n|\\
=&|A|^{-1}x^n |A-\frac 1x I_n|\\
=&(-1)^nx^n|A|^{-1}\psi_A(x)\\
=&(-1)^nx^n|A|^{-1} p(x)
\end{align*}

In this way, we can find the characteristic polynomial for $A^{-1}$ in terms of the characteristic polynomial for $A$. But I am not sure about my work.

My Second attempt: Given that $p(x)=\psi_A(x)$. Now if $\lambda$ be eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^{-1}$ will be eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. If q(y) be characteristic polynomial for $A^{-1}$ then $y=\frac 1x$. In other words, substituting the transformation $x=\frac 1y$ we have $p(\frac 1y)$ as the characteristic polynomial for $A^{-1}$.

hence $\psi_{A^{-1}}(x)=\psi_A(x^{-1})=p(x^{-1})$.

Now, please tell me, which one is true? I am completely confused now.

More over, I am unable to solve for adj$(A)$. Kindly help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the adjugate matrix:
$$\operatorname{adj}(A)=\det(A)A^{-1}=:\lambda A^{-1}$$
and then

$$\psi_{\operatorname{adj}(A)}(x)=\det(xI_n-\lambda A^{-1})=\lambda^n\det\left(\frac x{\lambda}I_n-A^{-1}\right)=\lambda^n\psi_{A^{-1}}\left(\frac x{\lambda}\right)$$

and for the inverse matrix your work is fine just you have one mistake and you should write:
$$\psi_{A^{-1}}(x)=(-1)^n|A|^{-1}x^n\psi_A\left(\frac1x\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't noticed that. Please clear my doubt.

(1) What about my second attempt? Is it correct? If yes, then will it be equal to the solution in my first attempt?

(2) The idea you provided for adj$A$ is really cool. But my question is, in case $A$ is singular, then how to proceed for characteristic polynomial of adj$A$?

Comment: Your second attempt is wrong: notice that $\psi_{A^{-1}}(x)$ should be a polynomial and clearly $p\left(\frac1x\right)$ it isn't! Your question is about $A$ **non-singular**, isn't it?

Comment: And what about adj$A$ for singular $A$??