# How to get characteristic polynomial of adj$(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $\mathop{A}\limits_{n\times n}$ be a singular matrix which characteristic polynomial is $\psi_A(x)$. How to find the characteristic polynomial for adj$(A)$ ?

I know what to do for non-singular case found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924632/what-should-be-the-characteristic-polynomial-for-a-1-and-adja-if-the-char). But I don't know the case for singular case. Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{\operatorname{adj}}$If $\rank A < n - 1$, then $\adj(A) = 0$, and so has characteristic polynomial $x^n$.

If $\rank A = n - 1$, then $0 \ne \adj(A)$ has rank $1$ (since $A \adj(A) = 0 \implies \text{im}(\adj(A)) \subseteq \ker A$, and $\dim \ker A = 1$), say $\text{im}(\adj(A)) = \text{span}(v)$ for some $v \ne 0$. Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $\adj(A)$, say with eigenvalue $\lambda$, so the characteristic polynomial of $\adj(A)$ is $x^{n-1}(x - \lambda)$. Notice that in this case, $\lambda = \text{tr}(\adj(A))$, which can be $0$.

Comment: Beautiful answer indeed